# Doesn't show Export to YAML option in our classic pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

As [mentioned in azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops) I was expecting an "Export to YAML" option.

It doesn't show Export to YAML option in our classic pipeline.
We only see Export option that downloads Json data.

Is any specific permission required to see Export to YAML option in classic pipeline?

[image]

It doesn't show Export to YAML option

Answer (score 1):

This feature is enabled for **Classic build pipelines**, but not for **Classic Release Pipelines**.

There are tools that can [export from Classic Release to YAML: yamlizr](https://github.com/f2calv/yamlizr).

```
yamlizr generate `
  -pat abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij `
  -org https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg `
  -proj MyProject `
  -out c:/temp/myoutputfolder `
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information. I tried to follow  yamilzr link and tried to install first .net 6 sdk. While running command : dotnet tool update --global yamlizr                          got an error : restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'yamlizr (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net6.0'.

Comment: The docs should say `dotnet tool install --global yamlizr` instead. `update` works once you have a working installation.